# Laravel handle routes in case of subdomain and main domain

Tags: laravel, subdomain, wildcard

I'm using Laravel routing subdomains to handle all subdomains. It works fine for the subdomain, but when I customize the routes for the primary domain routes is overwritten I think it because the route names are fixed for both subdomain and main domain so what is the proper way to handle this issue?

This is what is in my routes file at present;

```
Route::domain('{company}.' . config('app.url'))->group(function () {
    include "allRoutes.php";
});

Route::domain(config('app.url'))->group(function() { 
    include "allRoutes.php";
});
```

[enter image description here][1]

here is part of the content of the allRoutes.php file
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzm0F.png

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of your allRoutes.php file. Also you are including the same file in both domains, is this correct?

Comment: Ok i added the content of the allRoute.php file

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks as though you're having trouble when referencing routes because they are using the same name.

You should provide a name for your domained routes which effectively namespaces the naming.

```
Route::domain('{company}.' . config('app.url'))->name('sub.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});

Route::domain(config('app.url'))->name('main.')->group(function() { 
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Then later when referencing these you'll be able to use

`route('sub.home', ['company'])` for the subdomain route and
`route('main.home')` for the main domain

Comment: Ok, bro thanks you for your answer but i have lots of routes in my application  and the for this example the actual route in my view is route('main.routeName')
my problem is how can i make it dynamic when using subdomains add name('sub.') to all views and vice versa

Comment: can i use same routes in both sub domain and main domain with dynamic route name ?

Comment: What you're trying to do I don't really believe is possible without really making some helper functions. Would it not make more sense to place your main url onto a subdomain so all bits which share the the same routes all use subdomains? Don't forget www. is a subdomain - so that might be a work around